# Give role when a user add reaction (C# Discord.net)

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I want to assign a role to a user upon someone clicking the "OK" reaction, using the discord API. However I'm getting an error on line 43 of my code (identified below).

Console log:

```
 Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient[0]
  Gateway: A ReactionAdded handler has thrown an unhandled exception.
  System.InvalidOperationException: This property has no value set.
     at Discord.Optional`1.get_Value()
     at Template.Services.CommandHandler.OnReactionAdded(Cacheable`2 arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3) in C:\Users\Paul\Source\Repos\Discord.NET-Template\Template\Services\CommandHandler.cs:line 43
     at Discord.EventExtensions.InvokeAsync[T1,T2,T3](AsyncEvent`1 eventHandler, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
```

My Code:

```
public override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _client.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    _service.CommandExecuted += OnCommandExecuted;
    _client.ReactionAdded += OnReactionAdded;
    await _service.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _provider);
}
private async Task OnReactionAdded(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel arg2, SocketReaction arg3)
{
    if (arg3.MessageId != 842517264716136469) return;
    if (arg3.Emote.Name != "✅") return;
    var role = (arg2 as SocketGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(842522201881837585);
    await (arg3.User.Value as SocketGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role); //This is line 43
}
```

There is something wrong with this `arg3.User.Value` expression.
I would be glad to have any help with this problem.

Comment: Not familiar with the discord API but the error is telling me that `SocketReaction.User` is not set or being passed in `arg3`. You can confirm this by testing `if (arg3.User==Null) throw someException`

Comment: I would strongly suggest debugging and checking out what arg3.User looks like. There's some suggestion on Github that brand-new-to-the-server users may be null in API methods like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is correct.
It was necessary to enable gateway intents in the bot configuration.

these, under the bot tab at https://discord.com/developers/applications/

screenshot: [Bot Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5XAU.png)